# Відповідники слова "портфоліо"

Tags: вживання-слів

Вже тривалий час для позначення збірки виконаних робіт використовують слово ***"портфоліо"***, від англійського *portfolio*(знач.2)

[Загальний народний англійсько-український словник 2010–](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%20portfolio&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> **portfolio** [ˌpɔːtˈfəʊli‿əʊ, амер. ˌpɔːrtˈfoʊlioʊ ˌpoʊrt-]
>
> 1) портфе́ль, те́ка (для документів чи паперів)
>
> 2) портфе́ль, ***підбірка робіт (фотографа, художника…)***
>
> 3) портфе́ль, поса́да міністра
>
> 4) портфе́ль цінних паперів

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/portfolio) пропонують декілька варіантів відповідників:

> доробок, наробок, творотека, робітка, творозбірка.

В СУМ присутні

> **[доробок](http://sum.in.ua/s/dorobok)** *(1. Те, що зроблене, створене ким-небудь.2. діал. Заробіток; прибуток.)*, **[робітка](http://sum.in.ua/s/robitka)** ( и, жін., зневажл. Те саме,
>   що робота 1, 3, 7.).

Проте вони не передають те значення, яке потрібне.

Можливо існують ще якісь відповідники? Який відповідник можна вживати в діловому мовленні?

Comment: Чому слово "доробок" не передає потрібного значення? Адже портфоліо - це роботи, які були виконані певною людиною

Answer (score 1):

Взагалі-то, слово *доробок*, на мою думку, найкраще виступає у значенні портфоліо, адже воно не обов'язково використовується у значенні "творчої спадщини".
Можна використовувати слово *огляд* у значенні, яке пропонує [СУМ:](https://sum.in.ua/s/oghljad)

> 5. Стисле повідомлення про ряд подій, явищ і т. ін., поєднаних спільною темою.

У діловому мовленні також використовують такі слова, як *резюме*, *репертуар*, *збірка робіт*, *збірник*, *досьє*.